# How to keep table prompts connected in OBIEE?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, analysis, obiee

I am using OBIEE 12c and have an analysis that contains a table with two table prompts. 
What I am getting is that when I choose values for prompts I see the corresponding result, but when I then  change the value of one of them, the other one is not keeping its old value. Is it normal way behavior? I want the prompt to keep the old value when the other prompt is changed. Is it possible?

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you talking about in-line table prompts in the analysis object itself? So the ones which only visually rearrange data erather than filtering.  Not dashboard prompts which actually change the query and filter the data stream.

Comment: Yeah, I am talking about the table prompts which are created in analysis itself for the table view. They are nor a dashboard prompt, not a column prompt of an analysis. They are  related to table view and appear inside an analysis, not before opening analysis like column prompts do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not normal behaviour. Just tried it on 12.2.1.2 and 12.2.1.4 with Firefox and Chrome. For all four combinations the in-line table prompts when you change the second prompt, the first one stays on its selected value. When you change the first prompt then the second one also changes.

This is normal and expected behaviour since you never know if the currently selected value of prompt two actually exists for the - now new - value of prompts one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Chris. Now I got the difference that the order of prompts matter. Thanks again

Comment: Good. Could you please close your question once you have a valid answer? This will help other SO user.

Comment: Yes, sure. Forgot that